# Android: app is crashing

Tags: android

This is my code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   TextView editTextDay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editTextDay);
   editTextDay.setVisibility(8);    //GONE
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

without the line " editTextDay.setVisibility(8); " the app doesn't crash.

any idea on what's wrong ?

Comment: Nothing related to your question directly but you should use the constant View.GONE instead of 8.

Comment: @Laurent' I agree with the approach,
but for some reason eclipse won't recognize GONE and VISIBLE so I have to use 0 and 8 instead

Comment: @Laurent : i think it is the same , GONE is a constant of type int , his value is 8 ; refer this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE
Belgi : try EditText.GONE;

Comment: @Houcine - true, but it's more readable with GONE the only problem is that eclipse won't recognize that there is such a constant...

Comment: @Belgi : try : EditText.GONE  :)

Comment: @Houcine I think that you did not `import android.view.View;`

Comment: @Houcine is right.
(probably happened because I'm used to C)

Comment: @Laurent' : not me ,  that's why i've told him to try EditText.GONE , more than that : the EditText is a subclass of View :) , so it's the same ^^.

Comment: @Houcine  sorry I just mixed up the nicknames (I wanted to reach Belgi) ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**you should  set the content layout before any call of the method** : `findViewById()` ;that's why it return null . So your code will work like this :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   TextView editTextDay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editTextDay);
   editTextDay.setVisibility(8);    //GONE

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Move this line `setContentView(R.layout.main);` after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
.`Currently your textview is null so it is throwing exception. You first have to set view and then use findViewById method.

Answer (score 4):

Put setContentView right under the super call.
You can't access views before setting the content view:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   TextView editTextDay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editTextDay);
   editTextDay.setVisibility(View.GONE);    //GONE
}
```